# Citations as conference, year [STOC'13]

Tags: beamer, bibtex, citing

How can I cite like [STOC'13] ([Conference name'year])? in LaTeX beamer with bibtex?

I want a citation like Einstein~\cite{einstein2013} to appear like Einstein~[STOC'13]. The exact format is not that important, it could be [STOC, 2013] too.

Albert Einstein (2013)
On the theory of everything.
STOC, pages...

Comment: Please explain your issue better, for example by showing a short compilable tex code with used bib entry you have so far ...

Answer (score 1):

Try the alpha bib style:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{bibfilename}

\end{document}
```

with

```
@article{foo,
    author = {{Stockholm Super Conference}},
    year = {2013}
}
```

Comment: But when I add bibliography then there are no names of the authors.

Comment: @kyticka You could add the author in the title field.